# Как в одном обработчике для кнопок переключаться по имени?

Tags: c#

Как в одном обработчике для кнопок переключаться по имени кнопки по switch, case?

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;
        switch(b.Name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот так например:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Button b = sender as Button;
        switch(b.Name) {
            case "Name 1":
              doSomething1();
            break;
            case "Name 2":
              doSomething2();
            break;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы не поверите, но вот так :

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = sender as Button;
        switch (b.Name)
        {
            case "name1":
                MessageBox.Show("1");
                break;
            case "name2":
                MessageBox.Show("2");
                break;

        }
    }
```